# How to assign a new material to an object in the scene from Python?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, materials

How can I assign a new material to an object in the scene via Python?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Here you go, code with some safety checks:

```
import bpy
ob = bpy.context.active_object

# Get material
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Material")
if mat is None:
    # create material
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Material")

# Assign it to object
if ob.data.materials:
    # assign to 1st material slot
    ob.data.materials[0] = mat
else:
    # no slots
    ob.data.materials.append(mat)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it also possible to specifiy which material (glossy, glass, diffuse) and also the different properties (r,g,b, shinyness)?

Comment: Yes, it is also possible to manipulate the material nodes with python, but that is for another question

Comment: Amazing. These sanity checks actually helped me understand how the things work a lot!