# How to clean duplicate materials on multiple faces for all objects in C.scene? (In python)

Tags: python, materials

How can I fix this via script?
In this case the materials are all in use on an object, but they are the same material on multiple face, I would like to simplify it in 1 material only:

[image]

**Edit:**

in order not to make this question a possible duplicate, I want to specify that in this case I would like to iterate all the objects in the scene, and look for possible duplicate slots.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/129155/15543

Comment: @batFINGER I tried your script on a single object it works very well, but under a for loop or in C.scene.object, it seems to be very slow, a scene of about 250 objects, we are almost 20 minutes waiting, what do you think happens ?

Comment: Most likely https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators  If all materials are mesh linked then the material slot operators could be replaced.   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53366/how-can-i-replace-a-material-from-python

Comment: @batFINGER Ty for usefull info,I added the detail concerning all the objects in the scene in the question, in order to be more specific

Comment: @batFINGER Your script works well, just add the active object in the scene to each for loop, so it will work perfectly under a for loop