# Replace image in blender using script

Tags: python, scripting, image

It seems to be easy but as a beginner, I can not configure it.

I have four blocks with different images. I add all four images using *Images as Planes*. Now I want to replace all four images with different images running script.

[image]

Comment: Do you want switch the image in the material node or change the material?

Comment: @XY Sir, I want to replace the image with a new one every time so I think changing the material will be a good option. Any other solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: here is the ans to change material of a object: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53366/how-can-i-replace-a-material-from-python

Comment: @X Y Thanks, sir. I got the idea of how to change images with changing material. But it will be a huge help if you give some idea how to change images using material node.

Answer (score 2):

#### Change Image Texture image

```
import bpy

mats    = bpy.data.materials    # all materials store in here

mat     = mats["your Material"]      # get a material

tree    = mat.node_tree         # get node tree of the material

nodes   = tree.nodes            # all nodes in node_tree

for node in nodes:
    if node.type == "TEX_IMAGE":
        print(node.name)

node    = nodes["Image Texture"]    # get node by name of node

imgs    = bpy.data.images           # all image in blend file

img     = imgs["your img name"]     # get a image

node.image = img                    # change image in node

# node.image = None                 # change image to None
```

Comment: Thanks, sir to provide me with such valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to use a video texture.  if you encode with ffmpeg video and choose the webm encoder and setup trasnparency in the film render setting, the video can have transparency.