# Add material and apply Diffuse color via Python

Tags: python, materials, color

This may be another simple question but I can't seem to find a straight answer.

I am procedurally generating figures and as part of the last step I want to color the figure red.

If I manually add a new material to the figure I can change the color with `bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (1, 0, 0)`

But I need to automate this step such that the program automatically add a new material and then changes the color. I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
bpy.ops.material.new()
bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (1, 0, 0)
```

It seems the problematic step is adding a new material. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: creating a new material doesn't apply it to your active object

Comment: These are 2 questions asked and both have duplicates: 1: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/how-to-assign-a-new-material-to-an-object-in-the-scene-from-python/23434#23434, 2: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python/23446#23446

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out shortly after posting the question.

Instead of using:

```
bpy.ops.material.new()
```

I needed to use:

```
bpy.data.materials.new(name="MaterialName")
```

So the final solution was:

```
activeObject = bpy.context.active_object #Set active object to variable
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="MaterialName") #set new material to variable
activeObject.data.materials.append(mat) #add the material to the object
bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (1, 0, 0) #change color
```

Comment: Won't always work as obj.active_material will not necessarily be mat

Comment: Just use `mat.diffuse_color` (or `bpy.data.materials['Materialname'].diffuse_color`) instead.

Comment: You're a real hero!