# Can Driver Scripted Expressions access Node Group Inputs?

Tags: python, materials, drivers

I have a Material that consists of a single Node Group; one of the Node Group inputs is a scalar value named *Spot Z Rot*.

I'd like to add a driver to the Z rotation of an object, forcing it to match the Z Rot of this Node Group input. However, when I try to do this in various ways, the property is not recognized. I am able to access *Spot Z Rot* from the general scripting interface:

[image]

But when I try to do something similar in the Add Driver menu, *Spot Z Rot* is not recognized as a valid property of the Material:

[image]

So far I have tried, without success, the following:

```
bpy.data.node_groups['ToonShader'].inputs['Spot Z Rot']
data.node_groups['ToonShader'].inputs['Spot Z Rot']
node_groups['ToonShader'].inputs['Spot Z Rot']
self.inputs['Spot Z Rot']
```

As well as driving the rotation from an added custom property on the material. The driver does not seem to recognize any of these variables.

Is there a correct way of accessing a Material's Node Group Inputs from a Scripted Expression Python Driver on an object?

(Actually, even in the general Python scripting interface, I was a bit confused; [Getting the actual (not default) input value of a node group for a specific user](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77323/getting-the-actual-not-default-input-value-of-a-node-group-for-a-specific-user?rq=1) clarifies how access should work, but `node_tree.nodes.get('ToonShader').inputs['Spot Z Rot'].default_value` does not work in the Driver either.)