# How to load an image from disc and assign it to a newly created image texture node?

Tags: python, texturing, scripting, node-editor, image

I'm trying to load an image from jpeg file and to add the material to the cube using the following code:

```
bpy.ops.image.open(filepath="/root/carteid_dini.png", directory="/root/", files=[{"name":"carteid_dini.png", "name":"carteid_dini.png"}], relative_path=True, show_multiview=False)

# get material reference
mat = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active.active_material

# get texture reference
tex = bpy.data.images.get('carteid')

# create node and assing the texture to it
image_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
image_node.image = tex

mat.node_tree.links.new(image_node.outputs['Color'], mat.node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Base Color'], verify_limits=True)

cube = bpy.context.active_object


if len(cube.material_slots) == 0:
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()

cube.material_slots[0].material= mat
```

When I run this code, the newly created texture is unfortunately not loaded and the image is not selected for the 'Base Color'.

**Q:** How to load an image from the disc and and assign it to an arbitrary image texture node?

Comment: I don't know how to share this question via email from the web interface

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`BlendDataImages.load()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataImages.html?highlight=load#bpy.types.BlendDataImages.load) to *load* and *assign* the image to the texture node in one go. Following demo is based on [Control Cycles material nodes and material properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23446/31447).

Make sure there is a material assigned to the object in context and the file path is correct:

```
import bpy

# Get the active material of the object in context 
mat = bpy.context.object.active_material
# Get the nodes
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
nodes.clear()

# Add the Principled Shader node
node_principled = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
node_principled.location = 0,0

# Add the Image Texture node
node_tex = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
# Assign the image
node_tex.image = bpy.data.images.load("//your_image.exr")
node_tex.location = -400,0

# Add the Output node
node_output = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')   
node_output.location = 400,0

# Link all nodes
links = mat.node_tree.links
link = links.new(node_tex.outputs["Color"], node_principled.inputs["Base Color"])
link = links.new(node_principled.outputs["BSDF"], node_output.inputs["Surface"])
```

In case you'd like to use an image that *has been loaded or even is packed already*, you can get it via *image data-block* and assign that reference to [`ShaderNodeTexImage.image`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShaderNodeTexImage.html?highlight=image#bpy.types.ShaderNodeTexImage.image):

```
...

# Add the Image Texture node
node_tex = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
node_tex.location = -400,0
# Get the image and assign it to the Node.image
img = bpy.data.images.get("Image Name")
if img:
    node_tex.image = img

...
```

Related:

- [How to assign a new material to an object in the scene from Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/how-to-assign-a-new-material-to-an-object-in-the-scene-from-python)
- [Control Cycles/Eevee material nodes and material properties using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-eevee-material-nodes-and-material-properties-using-python)

Comment: AttributeError: "ShaderNodeOutputMaterial" object has no attribute 'image', any idea why?