# Using Python to add an HDRI to world node

Tags: python

How do I add in a blender python script a hdri to the world node.

```
scnworld = bpy.data.worlds.get("World")
scnImage = scnworld.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexEnvironment') 
scnImage.location = (-350, 250)
scnImage.image = bpy.data.images.load('H:\\blender__word_hdri\\green_sanctuary_2k.hdr') 
scnImage.image.colorspace_settings.name = 'Non-Color'
link = scnworld.node_tree.links.new –
```

Comment: here is some code but how do I link

Comment: scnworld  = bpy.data.worlds.get("World")
    scnImage = scnworld.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexEnvironment')
    scnImage.location = (-350, 250)
    scnImage.image = bpy.data.images.load('H:\\blender__word_hdri\\green_sanctuary_2k.hdr')
    scnImage.image.colorspace_settings.name = 'Non-Color'
    link = scnworld.node_tree.links.new

Answer (score 7):

Similar to [How to load an image from disc and assign it to a newly created image texture node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201412/how-to-load-an-image-from-disc-and-assign-it-to-a-newly-created-image-texture-no/) use [`BlendDataImages.load()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataImages.html?highlight=load#bpy.types.BlendDataImages.load) to *load* and *assign* the image to the *Environment Texture* node:

[image]

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
scn = C.scene

# Get the environment node tree of the current scene
node_tree = scn.world.node_tree
tree_nodes = node_tree.nodes

# Clear all nodes
tree_nodes.clear()

# Add Background node
node_background = tree_nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBackground')

# Add Environment Texture node
node_environment = tree_nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexEnvironment')
# Load and assign the image to the node property
node_environment.image = bpy.data.images.load("//hdri.exr") # Relative path
node_environment.location = -300,0

# Add Output node
node_output = tree_nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputWorld')   
node_output.location = 200,0

# Link all nodes
links = node_tree.links
link = links.new(node_environment.outputs["Color"], node_background.inputs["Color"])
link = links.new(node_background.outputs["Background"], node_output.inputs["Surface"])
```

Related: [Control Cycles material nodes and material properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23446/31447)