# Blender 2.9 - script how to add a material shader nodes tree?

Tags: python, materials, shaders, add-on

In blender 2.9, I got a selected object and need to add a new material in a new slot with a script addon. I need some examples for doing a material shader nodes tree in 2.9

Ex: How to adding some nodes like diffuse - glossy mix shader, doing the links setting parameters etc.. may there are some web link to help with that  for 2.9?

Comment: Nothing changed really for 2.9... https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes

Comment: [How to assign a new material to an object in the scene from Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/how-to-assign-a-new-material-to-an-object-in-the-scene-from-python)