# Interacting with material_slot in python

Tags: python

I am working on a project with mesh created with photogrammetry (mainly).
Once the mesh is imported, I would like to apply through scripts different materials before render them. But

- Sometimes, I use meshes with vertex color as color data, and they don't have any material's slot and I can't apply directly a material
- Sometimes, I use meshes with textures, and UV's are dispatched in several slots... so i need to fill every slot with a material

I would like to write something like this in Python:

```
for "material_slot" of selected object
    if there is no material_slot
        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()
    if there is only 1 slot and more
        do nothing

for every slot of selected object
    apply material "demoMat"
```

I am not fluent in Python grammar, and don't know how to write this.
Here is the documentation I found about [material_slot](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add) management...

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pythons built-in [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function on the [`Object.material_slots`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=object%20material_slots#bpy.types.Object.material_slots) collection to determine whether there are any material slots assigned to the objects material already. Suggest use the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) to figure out:

```
>>> C.object.material_slots
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].material_slots

>>> len(C.object.material_slots)
4
```

Following demo replaces all materials assigned to the given slots of the *object in context* ([`bpy.context.object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#id4)) by a material called "DemoMat". In case there is no material slot present the script appends a dedicated slot and assigns "DemoMat" as well:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
obj = C.object

# Get the material
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("DemoMat")
if mat is None:
    # Create the material if not present
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="DemoMat")

# Determine whether there are slots to work with
if len(obj.material_slots) > 0:
    # Assign the material to each slot 
    for c, slot in enumerate(obj.material_slots):
        obj.material_slots[c].material = mat
else:
    # In case there is no material, append the Demo material
    obj.data.materials.append(mat)
```

Related: [How to assign a new material to an object in the scene from Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/how-to-assign-a-new-material-to-an-object-in-the-scene-from-python)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It's working fine :)