# How to Assign Material to Object with Python?

Tags: python, materials

How can I change the material of my object (Hand) with Python?
I do not want to add a new material. I just want to assign an existing material.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/how-to-assign-a-new-material-to-an-object-in-the-scene-from-python

Comment: there's also `face.material_index` you can set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
 bpy.data.objects["Hand"].material_slots[0].material = bpy.data.materials['Material.001']
```